# nginx RegEx in location - get single letters

Tags: nginx

i want to catch a location and get the first 5 letters as variable in the location block, so that i can build a new path.

For Example:

```
location /direct/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.*) {
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/$1$2$3$4$5$6; }
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
location ~ "/direct/(?<myvar>.{5})(?<other_var>.*)" { use $myvar here }
```

Comment: Didn't work: nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "/direct/(?<first>."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?

Answer (score 0):

You can match the first 5 characters and pass those as `$1`:

```
location ~ "^/direct/([\w]{5})(.*)" {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/$1;
}
```

That would only pass the first 5 characters, so `http://example.com/12345abcdefg` would be passed to `http://example.com:1234/12345`, thereby dropping the remaining "abcdefg" in the original URI

Comment: Yes but i need it as single character not all in one.